# Equivalence Class Representatives vs Canonical Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I am being confused with the term CANONICAL FORM.

If I am considering an equivalence relation on a set of matrices, then I have equivalence classes. Can I call the representatives of each equivalence class as canonical forms of matrices under the operation/equivalence relation that I am considering?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I suggest caution on that. Different authors may have different canonical forms in mind; the phrase applies when large populations of mathematicians agree on the description of the "canonical" form. Example: for real symmetric matrices, equivalence relation $P^T AP$  for nonsingular $P.$ Some demand that the diagonal form so constructed have entries only $1,0,-1$ Which I dislike

Comment: @rrp_PH The implication of the term "canonical" form is that we have a unique (or in some cases "almost unique") representative of each equivalence class